# Reading NAS folders via powershell

Tags: powershell, nas

Hi :) Here's my problem:
I want to see how many subfolders my NAS has.
Via Google I found the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\<#NASIP#>\ | SELECT Attributes, Name, CreationTime | Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

I can extend this command so that I know how many (e.g. "8") there are at the end.
But now this command does not work as intended.
If I use the Pure IP: \\<#NASIP#>\ the following error is displayed:

```
Get-ChildItem : The path "\\<#NASIP##>\" cannot be found, because it does not exist.
```

If I now specify a subfolder e.g. pictures:  \\<#NASIP#>\pictures

```
                Attributes Name           CreationTime
                ---------- ----           ------------
System, Directory, Archive xxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxx 15:26:37
        Directory, Archive xxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxx 20:51:17
        Directory, Archive xxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxx 11:35:26
        Directory, Archive xxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxx 21:19:19
```

the command works without any problems and I get everything output correctly.
Does anybody know what this could be?

Greetings Zala

Comment: Try with `Get-ChildItem \\10.10.10.10\*`

Comment: I tested it. The command works as long as I don't get an error. But I don't get any output even if I put it into a variable.

Comment: "The command works as long as I don't get an error" - well, which one is it? Do you get and error or not with `*`?

Comment: Sry I tried this: `Get-ChildItem \\<#NASIP#>\*`
when I try to do that I get no output but no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Since the NAS does not share folders but shares, it does not work with Get-ChildItem. 
As an alternative I now do it via Net view. This works without problems.
An example how the command can look like:

```
net view \\$target /all | ?{$_ -match 'platte*'} | %{$_ -match '^(.+?)\s+Platte*'|out-null;$matches[1]}
```

Greetings Zala